# What are the limitations of a RDP session?

Tags: windows, remote-desktop, printer

I have two computers which I usually connect to with a Remote Desktop session (Win XP Pro and Windows Home Server).
It seems that not everything can be done using RDP.
Installing a driver for a HP all-in-one printer for example cannot be done successfully, the installation either gets stuck or the printer won't be recognized.
Same for several other devices that I tried to remotely install drivers.

My question is: What is the difference between using a computer directly or through RDP?
Which actions cannot be done through RDP?

Comment: I've managed to install both drivers and software without a problem. Are you sure it's because of RDP?

Comment: Yes, it's repeatable: RDP-no install, directly-works fine.
It's also not related to a specific Windows version, I use 2 different ones with the same results.

Comment: You've misspelled Windows in your tags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably are having issues with printer install if you have remote printing enabled.  The remote PC is using the local PC as it's default and it's causing an issue with printer installs.  Otherwise it should work.